# Is there anyway to wire a switch to a cable?

Tags: electrical-engineering

To summarize; I have two cables with 26 conductors inside. We have to unplug one cable to plug the other cable in, and the entire process is extremely cumbersome. I was trying find a switch or alternative method to connect both cables too, so we could easily flip between both inputs. Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Please, forgive my ignorance. I'm a MET intern who was given an electrical project, and I'm struggling in my research.

Comment: Can you please share some of your research? Also is it possible to share diagram or a picture?

Comment: I looked into two solutions. Either A) wiring both cables into a relay box or B) using a single pull double throw switch. But the relay box is really bulky. https://cnc-specialty-store.com/rs232-cables/db25-manual-switch-box-2-port?msclkid=95a136c158ce1a2d04b55462020ccd1a&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=RS%20-%20H&utm_term=4584345031716566&utm_content=RS232%20-%20H. I also couldn't find a way to use a SPDT switch for the multiple connections in the cable.

Comment: What do the wires carry ? Power or signals or both ? If signals, what frequency ? If the cables are VGA cables or HDMI cables, there are products available on the market to switch between cables.

Comment: They carry signals, but I'll have to find the exact specifications. The cables aren't VGA or HDMI, they're an industrial cable.

Comment: Forget the RS232 switch if your signals are something which cannot be quaranteed to be RS232.. The RS232 switch probably is an electronic circuit which works only with RS232 signals. I can be wrong. It can also be a pure multipole mechanical switch, but I do not believe it before I see. Show your cable ends and tell what functionality is controlled through those cables. Show the controller device, too. Know that most of us haven't got the gift of seeing missing facts as apparitions. We need photos, schematics, measurements and tech specs and just these things are asked in the earlier comments.

Comment: Just need one  DP26T switch :-).  I suspect you want to make sure whatever you end up with is a "break before make" switch.

Comment: One cannot prescribe a switch until you define the connectors and signal levels (EEG ? EMG ? industrial controller ? shielded pairs?

Comment: Get 26 SPDT switches.  All up, cable 1.  All down, cable 2.  Ye old KISS principle.

Comment: And if you want to make it one switch, bolt a bar across the 26 :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get low-cost off-the-shelf 25-way switchboxes, that have a single rotary switch to select between 2 (or 4) sets of inputs on D-type connectors. You'd need to check that the box switches all the 25 lines; a quick glance at a few datasheets suggests this is generally true. Search for 'DB25 switchbox'.

As others have said, you need to establish the nature of the signals you are switching, to make sure the voltage, current or frequency isn't too high.